# AWK script stops working after shell variables are added

Tags: awk, ksh

I have the code below (thanks to a member of this community) that is behaving weirdly. When I hard code the dynamic part it works... When I use parameters to run the code, it doesn't do anything. here is the code (both with and without variables) as well as outputs (Screenshots)

```
echo "Attempt A:"
echo "--------------------"
echo "awk -v n=4 '{a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n}
              /(Something)/{for(i=p;i<p+n-1;i++) print a[i%n];f=1}
              f{print}
              /\/Interface/{f=0}' file.log | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS=\"</Interface>\n -------------------\"}
      /name=\"Andy\"/' > AttemptA.txt"

awk -v n=4 '{a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n}
              /(Something)/{for(i=p;i<p+n-1;i++) print a[i%n];f=1}
              f{print}
              /\/Interface/{f=0}' file.log | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="</Interface>\n -------------------"}
      /Name="Andy"/' > AttemptA.txt

aaid="Andy"
aalog=file.log

echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo ""
echo ""
echo "Attempt B:"
echo "awk -v n=4 '{a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n}
              /(Something)/{for(i=p;i<p+n-1;i++) print a[i%n];f=1}
              f{print}
              /\/Interface/{f=0}' ${aalog} | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS=\"</Interface>\n -------------------\"}
      /Name=\"${aaid}\"/' > AttemptB.txt"

awk -v n=4 '{a[p]=$0; p=(p+1)%n}
              /(Something)/{for(i=p;i<p+n-1;i++) print a[i%n];f=1}
              f{print}
              /\/Interface/{f=0}' ${aalog} | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="</Interface>\n -------------------"}
      /Name="${aaid}"/' > AttemptB.txt
```

Here are the results(Screenshots):

Running the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j0PF.jpg

Files created: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMKKz.jpg

Any idea why it's recognizing everything, printing the same commands but one actually works and the other doesn't?

Comment: W.r.t. using `"${aaid}"` instead of `"Andy"` --- looks like you're trying to refer to a shell variable from inside the awk script. Awk doesn't have access to that.

Comment: you can embed a shell variable in an awk script by switching between single-quotes and dbl-quotes inside the awk script to "expose" the shell var value inside the awk script, i.e. `awk '/Name=' "${aaid}" '/ ......'` I have added a space between the single-quote and dbl-quote to make those chars stand out separately. Good luck.

Comment: Can either of you reply as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Thank you both!

Comment: ....and others of us can mark it as incorrect :-). Don't jump in/out of shell as @shelter suggests, use `-v aaid="$aaid" ... $0~("Name=\""aaid"\"")`. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 and just remember - awk is NOT shell.

Comment: LOL, I agree with Ed ;-/, `-v var="$val"` is the better solution, but I wanted you to realize that the shell single quote was preventing shell variable from being visible. For a one-off, sometimes it is a quicker solution than using `-v var="$val"` Good luck to all.

Comment: I find the shell quoting so hard to remember how to get right it takes me longer to figure it out (`x=3.0; awk 'BEGIN{print "'"$x"'"}'`) than it does to just do it the robust way (`x=3.0; awk -v x="$x" 'BEGIN{print x}'`) so I can't ever imagine a scenario where making a shell variables value expand to be an actual part of the awk script code (as the first version does) makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v aaid="$aaid" 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="</Interface>\n -------------------"}
    $0 ~ "Name=\""aaid"\""' > AttemptB.txt
```

Comment: Ok, so you're saying in -v I can create a bridge between awk and shell? how many variables can I define like this? how do I define multiple vars?

Comment: Exactly. `-v` is the way to pass values from the shell into awk. Similar to what you already had with `-v n=4`, instead of the hard-coded `4` you can just as easily use a shell variable. You can include the option multiple times, e.g. `-v color=red -v size=XL -v quantity=7`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you sir.